# POST key name for wsdl soap webservice

Tags: java, soap

I am currently using a POST Request from a Java client to access a SOAP webservice which uses WSDL files.

I do receive an answer from the webservice saying that my XML has problems. I believe that currently is not sending any XML. My question is what POST key do I have to set to my XML, which I want the webservice to use as the input?

Here's a code snippet of mine:

```
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content", input));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not receiving an error, I do receive a response from the webservice saying my XML is incomplete, because the webservice doesn't receive any XML, since I don't know which NameValuePair I need to use... My question is what do I have to change "Content" to @ example

Comment: If you are consuming soap webservices and have WSDL with you then why not create client stubs and make your life easy.

Comment: @subirkumarsao how would I go on about that?

Comment: You create your client using eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/WebServiceClient/WebServiceClient.html, You can also creates stubs using ant and other IDEs.

Comment: I need a program to do it, so I can do evaluations etc. aka inside program code